# Changing desktop background in bash

Tags: command-line, bash, scripts

I wanted to make a bash script that takes a random picture from a folder and sets it as the desktop background. I figured out the algorithm (it's not hard) but I can't find a command that would change the background picture if you give it the path to the picture.

I found `gconftool` for bash 2.~ and `gsettings` for bash 3.~, but i have GNU bash, version 4.3.42(1)-release on Ubuntu 16.04 LTS and these don't work.

Comment: What command did you use ? you can set a bg image with several tools from feh to nitorgen -

Comment: gconftool and gsettings aren't dependent on the version  of bash, and nobody uses anything older than bash 4 on any current Ubuntu system.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Assuming you're using standard Ubuntu 16.04 with Unity, you can use the following command to set the wallpaper:

```
gsettings set org.gnome.desktop.background picture-uri "file:///home/username/path/to/image.jpg"
```

You should also look at [Variety wallpaper changer](http://peterlevi.com/variety/) - it does the same thing as what you want to do with a shell script, with *a lot* of features and options.

Comment: I just typed in this command without puting file://... in "" and it worked! This entire time the quotation marks were being the problem

Comment: Working as described with quotation marks in 16.04.

Comment: for me, it worked with file:///... but without any quotes. Tested on Ubuntu 20.04 and CentOS 8

Answer (score 1):

I've done it like this:

```
targetDir="/home/username/Photos"


function get_next_photo() {
    # Returns a random file form targetdir
    files=( "$targetDir"/* )
    echo "${files[RANDOM % ${#files[@]}]}"
}

function set_background() {
    # Takes an absolute file path as argument. Need * for spaces in path
    bg="$*"
    echo "Setting background to $bg"
    gsettings set org.gnome.desktop.background picture-uri "file://$bg"
}


background=$(get_next_photo)
echo "Next background is $background"
set_background $background
```

Then add a quick launcher for your script to the dock, and you can change your wallpaper in one click.