# Can't change the wallpaper anymore

Tags: unity, 16.10, desktop-background

I am running Ubuntu 16.10, and I can't change the wallpaper.

I'm able to right click and get to the settings where I can select from a list of wallpapers; but whatever I select in there doesn't change the actual wallpaper: it keeps the default Ubuntu wallpaper.

How do I fix that? I guess my settings got corrupted somehow, which files do I have to delete to reset Unity?

Comment: Can you try this? https://askubuntu.com/questions/783558/changing-desktop-background-in-bash

Comment: The command `gsettings set org.gnome.desktop.background picture-uri "file:///usr/share/backgrounds/DSC3907_by_Todor_Velichkov.jpg"` doesn't change the wallpaper.

Comment: Omit the quotation marks from that command.

Comment: No difference, with or witout quotes

Comment: Does `gsettings list-schemas | grep "background"` return anything? Your background picture choice is a dconf setting which should be stored in `~/.config/dconf/user` which should be automagically re-created should you move or rename it, maybe that would help. I can't think of a cause for your inability to change the wallpaper though.

Comment: THat's what I get
```$ gsettings list-schemas | grep "background"
org.gnome.desktop.background
org.gnome.settings-daemon.plugins.background
```

Comment: It should also have returned `org.gnome.desktop.background`, which is what we were trying to change with `gsettings` above. Weird. Did you try moving / renaming the dconf/user file?

Comment: @kurja Quoting , particularly single quotes,  is necessary in such command, especially to prevent shell interpretation of special characters by shell.